# MySQL substring/in array performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, substring

I am selecting rows from a MySQL table like this:

```
SELECT id, name, code FROM table
```

What I want to do now is to select rows where code starts with a sequence of characters specified in an array. What is best practice - a) to change the MySQL query and use SUBSTRING and IN, or b) use PHP to filter the rows later?

a)

```
$qsql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, code FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(code, 1, 2) IN ('AB', 'BA', 'ZK', ...)");
while($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsql)) {
    // Do something
}
```

or b)

```
$codes = array('AB', 'BA', 'ZK', ...);
$qsql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, code FROM table");
while($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsql)) {
    if(!in_array($sql['code'], $codes))
        continue;
    // Do something
}
```

The code array will probably have ~30 elements.

Comment: will the list change dynamically? Is AB, BA defined once and will always be the same?

Comment: add output of table data and explain with example

Comment: "Starts with" can be optimised in MySQL with an index. Besides that, it reduces traffic between the two.

Comment: The list is pretty static. It might change, but probably not that often (few times a year).

Comment: The table "table" is updated with new data every second so I'd rather not add any extra indexes to it.

Comment: with only like 30 elements, just go with what is most convenient.  When in doubt, do the work on the DB side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Let SQL do its thing whenever possible. It'll almost always be faster then processing the data later. SQL is great at managing/filtering data, so when possible, have SQL process data.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of LIKEs dynamically.

```
$codes = array('AB', 'BA', 'ZK', ...);
$qsql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, code FROM table WHERE code LIKE ('".implode("%','", $codes)."%')");
while($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsql)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Assuming codes is sanitised